# Write a query to display the names of all students who have secured more than 50 in all subjects that they have appeared in?

Tags: sql

I have been learning sql in online. I have some doubts in this question.
Tis is my answer but it didnt work properly.

**Answer:**

```
select distinct student_name 
  from student s 
  join mark m on s.student_id=m.student_id
 where value > 50 order by student_name;
```

[image]

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: BTW, your query will return the students having > 50 in one or more classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is close. You just need to check that all marks are > 50, not just one. You can do that by grouping by student_id and using a `HAVING` clause to assert that all marks are > 50, which is the same as the minimum mark being > 50:

```
SELECT s.student_name 
FROM student s
JOIN mark m ON s.student_id=m.student_id
GROUP BY s.student_name
HAVING MIN(m.value) > 50
ORDER BY s.student_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check if the count for all subject  and for subject  > 50 for a studen is equale

```
  select m.student_id, count(*) tot_50_count
  from  mark m 
  where m.value > 50 
  gropup by m.student_id 

  select distinct student_name from student s 
  join (
      select m.student_id, count(*)  tot_count
      from  mark m 
      group by m.student_id 
  ) t1 on t1.student_id = s.student_id 

  join (
    select m.student_id, count(*) tot_50_count
    from  mark m 
    where m.value > 50 
    group by m.student_id 
  ) t2  on t2.student_id = s.student_id  
      and t1.tot_count = t2.tot_50_count
```