# students names and their marks in Computer Programming

Tags: oracle

Write a query to display the students names and their marks in Computer Programming order by marks in ascending order and then ordered by name in descending order. Give an alias to marks as CP_MARKS.

i have tried this one.

```
     select student_name, value from
        (select subject_id, student_id 
        from student s, subject su, mark m 
        where s.student_id=m.student_id 
        and su.subject_id=m.subject_id
        group by student_id
        order by student_id)
        where subject_name='Computer Programming'
        order by value;
```

This is the schema :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you know that **very same image** is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161272/write-a-query-to-display-the-names-of-all-students-who-have-secured-more-than-50/52161460) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55751081/top-performer-in-software-engineering) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725183/write-a-query-to-find-the-name-of-the-students-who-has-scored-maximum-mark-in)! Hopefully your instructor doesn't know how to use Google Image Search, like I did. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables `mark`, `student` and `subject`, by using proper joins. 
Then apply the condition `subject_name = 'Computer Programming'` and finally order the result:

```
select 
  st.student_name,
  m.value CP_MARKS
from mark m
inner join student st on st.student_id = m.student_id
inner join subject su on su.subject_id = m.subject_id
where su.subject_name = 'Computer Programming'
order by m.value, st.student_name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_name,value as CP_MARKS
    from mark m inner join student s
    on s.student_id=m.student_id
    where subject_id=(select subject_id from subject where lower(subject_name)='computer_programming')
    order by value asc ,student_name desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

select s.student_name,m.value as cp_marks
from student s
join mark m on s.student_id=m.student_id
join subject su on su.subject_id=m.subject_id
where s.subject_name='COMPUTER PROGRAMMING' or 'computer programming'
order by m.value,s.student_name desc;